# How can I re-calculate the common exponent?

Tags: python

To explain this, this is basically a way to shrink floating point vector data into 8-bit or 16-bit signed or unsigned integers with a single common unsigned exponent (the most common of which being `bs16` for precision with a common exponent of 11).

I'm not sure what this pseudo-float method is called; all I know is to get the resulting float, you need to do this:

```
float_result = int_value / ( 2.0 ** exponent )
```

What I'd like to do is match this data by basically *guessing* the exponent by attempting to re-calculate it from the given floats.
(if done properly, it should be able to be re-calculated in other formats as well)

So if all I'm given is a large group of 1140 floats to work with, how can I find the common exponent and convert these floats into this shrunken `bu8`, `bs8`, `bu16`, or `bs16` (specified) format?

EDIT: samples

```
>>> for value in array('h','\x28\xC0\x04\xC0\xF5\x00\x31\x60\x0D\xA0\xEB\x80'):
   print( value / ( 2. ** 11 ) )

-7.98046875
-7.998046875
0.11962890625
12.0239257812
-11.9936523438
-15.8852539062
```

EDIT2:
I wouldn't exactly call this "compression", as all it really is, is an extracted mantissa to be re-computed via the shared exponent.

Comment: Please give some sample inputs/outputs.

Comment: As @JohnColeman mentioned it (the comment is gone now), you would lose some precision by converting the floats in ints and back again. Still I think is kind of an optimization problem. What you could do is try out a bunch of exponents and pick the one with the smallest MSE

Comment: I think I understand the question now. The floats in question are a result of the calculation `float_result = int_value / ( 2.0 ** exponent )` for `int_values` of a given size but with unkown exponent and you want to recover the exponent. I don't think that this is possible in general. If a given exponent works in the sense that it yields integers in a given range, then that exponent + 1 might also work with int values that are twice as big. Many lists of numbers of a given size (e.g. 16 bits) have the property that their doubles are also of the same size.

Comment: @BloodyD At first I read it as a compression problem, and had a comment about the lossy nature of the compression, but I deleted that comment when I reread it as an inverse problem. The floats in question are not arbitrary floats.

Comment: @JohnColeman well you're not wrong about it being lossy, it's just like the comparison of an IEEE754 32bit float compared to a 64bit double... but that's about the only affection as compared to here... it's not meant to be perfect in precision. ;)

Comment: Is the exponent always a positive integer?

Comment: I do believe so, the only other format I've seen it in is `bu32`, but of course this is just overkill (as are most Havok formats)

Comment: I suggest you learn about logarithms. This will allow you to solve your equation for `exponent`.

Comment: tbh, it's because logarithms were mentioned in a local chat that I started looking into this again, but I'm working on it, thanks :)

Comment: @Code-Apprentice The equation has two degrees of freedom (neither `int_value` nor `exponent` are known) hence there isn't any specific number to take a logarithm of.

Comment: @JohnColeman The equation for `float_result` can still be manipulated to give an equation for `exponent` which is a function of two variables.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this:

```
def validExponent(x,e,a,b):
    """checks if x*2.0**e is an integer in range [a,b]"""
    y = x*2.0**e
    return a <= y <= b and y == int(y)

def allValid(xs,e,a,b):
    return all(validExponent(x,e,a,b) for x in xs)

def firstValid(xs,a,b,maxE = 100):
    for e in xrange(1+maxE):
        if allValid(xs,e,a,b):
            return e
    return "None found"

#test:

xs = [x / ( 2. ** 11 ) for x in [-12,14,-5,16,28]]
print xs
print firstValid(xs,-2**15,2**15-1)
```

Output:

```
[-0.005859375, 0.0068359375, -0.00244140625, 0.0078125, 0.013671875]
11
```

You could of course write a wrapper function which will take a string argument such as `'bs16'` and automatically compute the bounds `a`,`b`

**On Edit:**

1) If you have the exact values of the floats the above should work. It anything has introduced any round-off error you might want to replace `y == int(y)` by `abs(y-round(y)) < 0.00001` (or something similar).

2) The first valid exponent will be the exponent you want *unless* all of the integers in the original integer list are even. If you have 1140 values and they are in some sense random, the chance of this happening is vanishingly small.

**On Further Edit:** If the floats in question are not generated by this process but you want to find an optimal exponent which allows for (lossy) compression to ints of a given size you can do something like this (not thoroughly tested):

```
import math

def maxExp(x,a,b):
    """returns largest nonnegative integer exponent e with
a <= x*2**e <= b, where a, b are integers with a <= 0 and b > 0
Throws an error if no such e exists"""
    if x == 0.0:
        e = -1
    elif x < 0.0:
        e = -1 if a == 0 else math.floor(math.log(a/float(x),2)) 
    else:
        e = math.floor(math.log(b/float(x),2))
    if e >= 0:
        return int(e)
    else:
        raise ValueError()

def bestExponent(floats,a,b):
    m = min(floats)
    M = max(floats)
    e1 = maxExp(m,a,b)
    e2 = maxExp(M,a,b)
    MSE = []

    for e in range(1+min(e1,e2)):
        MSE.append(sum((x - round(x*2.0**e)/2.0**e)**2 for x in floats)/float(len(floats)))

    minMSE = min(MSE)
    for e,error in enumerate(MSE):
        if error == minMSE:
            return e
```

To test it:

```
>>> import random
>>> xs = [random.uniform(-10,10) for i in xrange(1000)]
>>> bestExponent(xs,-2**15,2**15-1)
11
```

It seems like the common exponent 11 is chosen for a reason.

Comment: I'm gonna do some extended testing in time to see just how close this logic is to the many various formats out there, and then see how well it can reduce the data used on full `bf32` formats where supported. I'll mark this as accepted if everything performs well. :)

Comment: @Tcll if you want to allow for an error tolerance you should use something like `abs(y-round(y)) < 0.00001` rather than `abs(y-int(y)) < 0.00001` (as I had in my first edit) so that negative numbers are handled correctly.

Comment: yea, I don't think this is exactly great, it only seems to work if the floats are derrived from this format, it doesn't attempt to optimize them further or pre-calculate another exponent... the idea is to try to re-perform the initial calculations that derrived the initial exponent to begin with... obviously it's possible or we wouldn't have the int values in the first place.

Comment: @Tcll Your problem was stated as one of *restoring* the `int` data and the unknown exponent given the `float` data (you used the phrase "convert these floats back"). If you have floats that aren't derived from this process and want to find an algorithm to compress them in an optimal way, that is a fairly different question. Perhaps you can even post it as such, or at least edit the question so that it doesn't sound like the goal is to restore lost `int` data (but is instead to create the `int` compressions starting from arbitrary `float` data).

Comment: alright, I've edited to title as such, but I can try to edit the question too... re-calculating the exponent is initially what I wanted to do... it is the "proper" way after all. ;)

Comment: @Tcll I have some ideas about how to tweak the code to answer the (implicit) second question. I'll do so if I have time later today.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132897/discussion-between-tcll-and-john-coleman).

Comment: @Tcll Unfortunately my work schedule today doesn't lend itself to that. You could always send me an email.

Comment: @Tcll A parting thought -- if all of the floats are of the same (or nearly the same) exponent in their internal representation, this exponent can be deduced from `math.frexp()`. The code I gave above for minimizing MSE is mostly relevant for the case of an arbitrary list of floats of possibly widely differing magnitudes. In simpler cases it is overkill.

Answer (score 1):

If you've got the original values, and the corresponding result, you can use log to find the exponent. Math has a log function you can use. You'd have to log Int_value/float_result to the base 2.

EG:

```
import Math
x = (int_value/float_result)
math.log(x,2)
```

Comment: the idea is to find the exponent with the floats only

Comment: @Tcll What is `int_value`? Is this the integer part of the float?

Comment: As @Joshua mentioned it's meant for the known value, which defeats the idea... sure you can save the values on load, but it's better if you can compute the proper exponent from the start. (no loss or gain with matching results)